# What files are created when using useradd

Tags: linux, useradd

Which files will be created when using the command `useradd` ?

I know that it will modify `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/shadow` and that it copies home/skel to the user's home directory.  I want to know which files such as (say) `.bash_logout` are created by default.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. There are several files created, modified and copied. What is the issue you are facing? Are you asking because you want to bypass `useradd`?

Comment: This question is answered in detail in the man page.

Comment: I know /etc/passwd , /etc/group , /etc/shadow will modify and home/skl will copy user's home directory.

Comment: My question is which file will be create by default e.g - .bash_logout

Comment: See the manual.  It will mention something called a "skeleton directory" (`/etc/skel`). This would be used if `-m` is used with `useradd`.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Kusalananda, `useradd -m rahul` will create a new user *rahul* and set up his home directory. The files contained there are the ones defined in the skeleton dir `/etc/skel`. For instance on my system this dir contains:

```
[dr01@centos7 ~]$ ls -lap /etc/skel
total 28
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   92 May 16 10:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 143 root root 8192 Sep 21 09:46 ../
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   18 Apr 11 02:53 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  193 Apr 11 02:53 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  231 Apr 11 02:53 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root   39 Mar 19  2018 .mozilla/
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  658 Aug  2  2017 .zshrc
```

This directory is referenced in `useradd`'s manpage.